# New line in TEXT #ORACLE

Tags: oracle, text, oracle-sqldeveloper, newline

I want to have as an output of my query the following text:

```
hello 
world
```

I tried to add chr(10)/chr(13) in my query but in doesn't work. Does anybody have any idea what's going on here ? I can add that I'm using Oracle, and on daily basis I'm working with SQL Developer.

Please see SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4dc72f/407

Thanks so much for help!

Comment: What output are you getting?  I see the hello and world on separate lines but I cut and pasted the result into a tool that understands those characters.

Comment: Consider [this](https://rextester.com/YKJ76435)

Comment: Okay, in SQL Developer i see: hello world

Comment: It appears to be an issue with how the client renders the output. I ran your code on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5124346ad567f05c3b9066f6c497d726) and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I can think of.

**One** is to run the query (`select 'hello' || chr(10) ||'world' from dual;`, right?) using the "Run statement" toolbar button (or hit Ctrl + Enter). The result will be written as one word (`helloworld`). Double-click it; a pencil button will appear right to the result so - click it. A new window opens and shows the result properly,

```
hello
world
```

**Another** is to run the query as a script (either using the toolbar button, or press F9). The result will be displayed correctly.

That goes for SQL Developer 18.3; can't tell for other versions.

Comment: Confirmed for SQL Developer 14.48 as well.